# Cosine theorem in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

In an euclidean space, given the rectangle with vertices $A,B,C$ the cosine theorem states:
$\overline{AB}^2=\overline{BC}^2+\overline{AC}^2-2\overline{AC}\dot{}\overline{BC}\dot{}\cos(\widehat{AC BC})$. If we have a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ and so: $dx^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{nu}$ what is the new expression of the cosine theorem in the new space? For example, in the simple case of spherical trigonometry how does the theorem change? Thanks.

Comment: The answer would depend on the size of the triangle. For example, take this triangle with all angles equal 90 degrees: North Pole and 2 points on Equator at longitude 0 and 90. The above formula would be grossly incorrect; on the other hand, for "small" triangles, small relative to curvature radii, the above formula is essentially correct. The answer to you question is available for the "simple cases" of constant curvature spaces (just don't have it handy), but I doubt one can derive something as simple for variable curvature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spherical case, you can look at the [Wikipedia article,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) and similarly in the [hyperbolic case.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) In general, you get something disgusting, so people have proved comparison theorems instead, which say that for a small triangle with sides $a, b, c$ in space $Y$ the angles are bigger than those in a "model space" $X,$ if the (sectional) curvature of $Y$ is bigger than that of $X.$ For more, search for [Toponogov comparison theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toponogov%27s_theorem) (there is a huge area of research known as the study of CAT(?) spaces (? can be 0 or 1 or -1), which are spaces with curvature bounds. Just do a search for, e.g., CAT(0).